# Main report border not aligning with sub report

Tags: reporting-services

Main issue i am facing in most of the reports where i have multiple sub reports for each main report in most of the reports,Couldn't possibly align the sub report borders with the main report.

Sub report and main report both are dynamically increasing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's largely correct.  Tablix column widths do not dynamically adjust, and subreports do not have direct visibility of their parent's properties regardless.  That means that you can't set up fixed width reports with %-width columns, and you can't make subreports autosize to an element of their parent report.

That being said, there is a potential method for simple tables.  However, it is moderately involved and a little limited:

You can create a number of "spacer" columns and set their visibility depending on the distinct count of your column groups.  This causes each table to end up the same size.  You would need to set up your row headers as an adjacent group so that you can toggle their column visibility.  You'd also need to set up the columns to be uniform size across tables.

This would require you to know:  The maximum number of columns that could be generated (so you know how many spacer columns to create).  And the current number of columns to size to, unless you just size to the maximum every time.  If that current column number could be determined in the parent report, it could be passed to the subreports as an internal parameter.

The setup would look like this:

[image: Setting up a spacer.]

Comment: Couldn't exactly figure out the solution.i have 4 merged cells in the main report and have the 4 cells data in the sub report. 
Data is populating correctly but the problem is with the border.
If my main report data is bigger than sub report data then the sub report border is not extending.